# Configuring watchman in ember-cli

Tags: javascript, ember-cli, watchman

In my ember-cli app, .watchman config file, I've mentioned what directories to ignore while watching, like `"ignore_dirs": ["tmp"]`. Now I want to watch files in a directory which is outside my app directory. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Can you clarify the following? As far as I understood it, you want to watch changes outside your ember `app` folder, which means on the project's root level. E.g. your `tmp` folder which you are already ignoring in your `.watchmanconfig` file is also living on the project's root level. 
Do I understand it correctly, that you want to watch changes in other sibling folders of `tmp`, e.g. in `public` or `tests`?

Comment: @jessica Yes, I want to watch changes in sibling folders of tmp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you had an ember project called `my-ember-app` in which the directory structure would typically look something like this:

```
my-ember-app
 .watchmanconfig
 -- app
 -- bower_components
 -- config
 -- dist
 -- node_modules
 -- public
 -- tests
 -- tmp
 -- vendor
```

and if you wanted watchman to not only ignore changes in the `tmp` but also in the sibling folder `public`, your `.watchmanconfig` file would have to look like this:

```
{
  "ignore_dirs": ["tmp","public"]
}
```

You can find out more about the `ignore_dirs` option value of the `.watchmanconfig` file in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/config.html#ignore_dirs).

---

If that isn't working in your setup yet, make also sure that

### **Watchman is actually installed.**

Ember CLI doesn't come with watchman out of the box, so you will have to install this additionally. If you notice this message showing up in your terminal once you spin up your ember app with `ember serve`:

`Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events
Livereload server on http://localhost:49152
Serving on http://localhost:4200/`

watchman is not installed yet.
On OSX you can install Watchman using Homebrew: `brew install watchman` and installation instructions for other OS'es can be found in [the Watchman documentation](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#build-install).

### **the watch for your project is removed and readded after editing `.watchmanconfig`.**

[As stated in the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/config.html), watchman doesn't pick up on changes in your `.watchmanconfig` file automatically. For your new configuration to take any effect, move to the root of your ember project

`cd my-ember-app`

to first remove the watch

`watchman watch-del .`

and then re-add the watch

`watchman watch .`

You can check if the changes have been recognised by watchman correctly by using the command
`watchman get-config .`